# go lang Error:Field validation for '' failed on the 'required' tag

Tags: validation, go

My request is failing from other service even I am passing required query string parameters.
Here is validation code:

```
type ActionByRuleRequest struct {
    Code  string `json:"code" form:"code" query:"code" validate:"required,oneof=gde cse scc"`
    Name string `json:"name" form:"name" query:"name" validate:"required"` // Monitoring rule name
}
```

Here is validating query string with validation

```
func GetActionByRule(c echo.Context) error {
    // Get parameters from the query string
    req := new(model.ActionByRuleRequest)
    err := c.Bind(req);
    if  err != nil {
        log.Println(err)
        error := model.Error{
            Message: err.Error(),
        }
        responseError := &model.ResponseError{
            Status: http.StatusBadRequest,
            Code:   "INVALID_INPUT",
        }
        responseError.Errors = append(responseError.Errors, error)
        return echo.NewHTTPError(http.StatusBadRequest, responseError)
    }
    // Validate input
    log.Printf("[/action_by_rule] 00000000000 get req = %#v\n", req)

    v := validator.New()

    err = v.Struct(req); 

    if err == nil {
        log.Println("Input valid")
    } else {
        log.Println("Input validation failed:", err)
     }
}
```

Request URL:'http://127.0.0.1:3015/action?code=csf&name=tbiubi-csf-rule'

Error:

```
 Key: 'ActionByRuleRequest.Code' Error:Field validation for 'Code' failed on the 'required' tag
Key: 'ActionByRuleRequest.Name' Error:Field validation for 'Name' failed on the 'required' tag
```

Comment: got any fix for this?

Comment: Found any solution? then share with us.